# gdb: break vs run

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

Let's say I set a breakpoint with `break my_func` in gdb, then type `run`. gdb executes the code until it hits the breakpoint. But what happens when I hit `run` again?

Will gdb continue into the breakpoint code, or will it skip past the breakpoint, or will it restart the code from line 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what happens when I hit run again?

The program is restarted.

If you want to "step over the breakpoint" and continue execution, use `continue` command.